# ActiveAndroid Update() query

Tags: android, android-sqlite, activeandroid

I'm trying to make a bulk update to a column using ActiveAndroid. Here's my code:

```
new Update(SomeModel.class).set("Enabled = 0").execute();
```

<strike>But I'm getting a `StackOverflowError`.</strike> (Edit: My bad, the error was somewhere else). Does anyone know how to execute an `Update()` query? It doesn't say anything in ActiveAndroid's wiki.

Edit:

This syntax is correct:

```
new Update(SomeModel.class)
  .set("Enabled = 0")
  .where("Account = ?", account.getId())
  .execute();
```

You can skip the `where` if not needed.

Comment: Can you add your stack trace?

Comment: @jlhonora why should you use .set("Enable = 0") .. P.S: I am new to Active Android ..

Comment: @Ajay because it's more performant than loading + saving. Specially if you have many items to update.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This syntax is correct:

```
new Update(SomeModel.class)
  .set("Enabled = 0")
  .where("Account = ?", account.getId())
  .execute();
```

You can skip the where if not needed.

Comment: is it valid to be `.set("Enabled = ?", 0)` ?

Comment: @Hamzeh yes, that's valid too

Answer (score 12):

Base on [AndroidActive's github](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Saving-to-the-database): "The save method works for both inserting and updating records."
So, if you want to update an item, first, you must read it from database, then modify it, and finally save it again.

For ex:

```
Foo for = Foo.load(Foo.class, 1);//1 is the id
foo.bar = "new value";
foo.save();
```

Comment: That is highly inefficient, specially if you need to update lots of items.

Comment: @jlhonora: if you wana save lots of items, let use `ActiveAndroid transaction` [from here](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Saving-to-the-database#bulk-insert). By the way, could you give a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something like this:

```
SomeModel model = selectField("fieldName", "fieldValue");
model.field = newValue;
model.save();
```

where `selectField()`method is:

```
public static SomeModel selectField(String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
    return new Select().from(SomeModel.class)
            .where(fieldName + " = ?", fieldValue).executeSingle();
}
```